# Is it possible to make Link left-handed in Zelda: Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword*, is it possible to play the game with a left-handed Link? Obviously, I can switch hands I use for the Wiimote and nunchuck, but that won't change how Link appears on-screen.

Comment: Look in a mirror?

Comment: This question needs the [tag:sinister] tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there's no left-handed mode, although there were lots of rumours. This [IGN editor's note](http://www.ign.com/blogs/bullseye2/2011/10/17/about-that-left-handed-mode-in-zelda-skyward-sword) confirms that from Nintendo itself.

> When sites started reporting our "news" we immediately started to have
>   second thoughts. Was there a left-handed mode? We consulted our
>   combined 50 pages of notes and realized we had made no such
>   observations. That lack of evidence caused me to quickly send an
>   inquiry to Nintendo for extra verification. However asking Nintendo a
>   question can take a little while, particularly if it's something a bit
>   off the radar or about a very specific game detail...
>
> ...Late, late last week I heard back from Nintendo that there was no so
>   such mode.

Comment: such a shame... Link's left-handedness was always one of his distinctive features before the Wiimote came onto the scene

Comment: I have since noticed that Link still shoots the bow and arrow left-handed.